# mount cephfs failed because of failure to load kernel module

Tags: linux, docker, ceph

I got a confused issue in docker as below:

After install ceph successfully, i want to mount cephfs but failed:

```
[root@dbffa72704e4 ~]$ /bin/mount 172.17.0.4:/ /cephfs -t ceph -o name=admin,secretfile=/etc/ceph/admin.secret -v
failed to load ceph kernel module (1)
parsing options: rw,name=admin,secretfile=/etc/ceph/admin.secret
mount error 5 = Input/output error
```

But ceph related kernel modules have existed:

```
[root@dbffa72704e4 ~]$ lsmod | grep ceph
ceph                  327687  0
libceph               287066  1 ceph
dns_resolver           13140  2 nfsv4,libceph
libcrc32c              12644  3 xfs,libceph,dm_persistent_data

Check the ceph state(i only set data disk for osd):

[root@dbffa72704e4 ~]$ ceph -s
  cluster:
    id:     20f51975-303e-446f-903f-04e1feaff7d0
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            Reduced data availability: 128 pgs inactive
            Degraded data redundancy: 128 pgs unclean

  services:
    mon: 2 daemons, quorum dbffa72704e4,5807d12f920e
    mgr: dbffa72704e4(active), standbys: 5807d12f920e
    mds: cephfs-1/1/1 up  {0=5807d12f920e=up:creating}, 1 up:standby
    osd: 0 osds: 0 up, 0 in

  data:
    pools:   2 pools, 128 pgs
    objects: 0 objects, 0 bytes
    usage:   0 kB used, 0 kB / 0 kB avail
    pgs:     100.000% pgs unknown
             128 unknown

[root@dbffa72704e4 ~]$ ceph version
ceph version 12.2.1 (3e7492b9ada8bdc9a5cd0feafd42fbca27f9c38e) luminous (stable)
```

My container is based on centos:centos7.2.1511.

I saw some ceph related images on docker hub so that i think above
operation is ok, did i miss something important?

Comment: This looks like a network communication error more than anything else.

Comment: Could you tell more detail or ways to check it?

Comment: Check that you can ping there server in question. Check that there is no firewall blocking the traffic, check that the required daemons are running on the server.

Comment: If it was a network problem, how would the OSDs have joined the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to comment yet, so don't consider this an answer (yet). The OSDs didn't join the cluster, there are none according to the output:

> osd: 0 osds: 0 up, 0 in

The "creating" state of your MDS suggests exactly that, it has no OSDs yet:

> mds: cephfs-1/1/1 up  {0=5807d12f920e=up:creating}, 1 up:standby

Mounting CephFS will fail until you have an active MDS running. Check the network settings and OSD logs to resolve the OSD issue first.